# Using acast on ffdf, large dataset

Tags: r

I have a large ffdf that I created from a 16GB delimited file. Pertient information is below.

```
ffdf (all closed) dim=c(793987635,3), dimorder=c(1,2) row.names=NULL
ffdf virtual mapping
            PhysicalName VirtualVmode PhysicalVmode  AsIs VirtualIsMatrix PhysicalIsMatrix PhysicalElementNo
uID                V1      integer       integer FALSE           FALSE            FALSE                 1
cID                V2      integer       integer FALSE           FALSE            FALSE                 2
value              V3       double        double FALSE           FALSE            FALSE                 3
            PhysicalFirstCol PhysicalLastCol PhysicalIsOpen
uID                     1               1          FALSE
cID                     1               1          FALSE
value                   1               1          FALSE
ffdf data
```

I'm attempting to run this
acast(data, "uID"~"cID", value.var="value")

But get an error
"Error: cannot allocate vector of size 5.9 Gb"

I'm just starting to work with ffdf and I'm wondering if what I am trying to do is impossible given the size of the data, or if there is some alternative to acast that I should be using instead.

The data right now is "normalized" but I'm looking at constructing a table out of it...

```
uID1 cID1 0.123
uID1 cID2 0.123
uID1 cID3 0.123
...
uID2000 cID1 0.123
uID2000 cID2 0.123
uID2000 cID3 0.123
...
...
```

The output I'm looking for is
uID cID1 CID2 CID3...

```
uID1 0.123 0.123 0.123
uID2 0.123 0.123 0.123
uID3 0.123 0.123 0.123
etc.
```

I have successfully used acast to do similar on smaller datasets, but I've never worked with 800 million rows before. There are about 200 cIDs per uID.

Any suggestions are appreciated, even if it's just informing that what I am trying to do is not possible.

Thank you.

Comment: You may look at `dcast.data.table` from `data.table`

Comment: Also you could check `spread` from `tidyr`

Comment: I don't think that will work because dcast.data.table requires the data to be in a data.table format and I can't convert this object into a physical RAM table. I'm going to read through the ff and ffbase documentation to see if there's something that I'm missing.

Comment: I stopped getting 'cannot allocate vector' error messages when inserted more RAM into my computer. Strongly recommended.

Comment: That's terribly unhelpful in this instance, but thanks anyway.